# How to call a php function within a HTML paragraph tag

Tags: php, html

I need to call a function to display the price of items using a HTML paragraph. Function name is `get_price($user_id , $product_id)`. HTML statement is mentioned below. Basically, I need to replace the `$<?=$price['price']` with that function.

```
$priceQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM size_price WHERE product_id = '$product_id' ORDER BY price");
$price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($priceQuery);
?>
<p class="text-center price">From $<?=$price['price']?></p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to include the above-mentioned function within the HTML statement?

Comment: `<p class="text-center price">From $<?=get_price($user_id , $product_id)?></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function get_price($product_id){
     global $db;

        $price = 0;
        if($priceQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `size_price` WHERE `product_id` = '$product_id' ORDER BY price")){
            $priceResults = $priceQuery->fetch_assoc($priceQuery);
            $price = $priceResults['price'];
        }
        return $price;
}
?>
<p class="text-center price">From $<?php echo get_price(100); ?></p>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the answer to the op  ?

Comment: That query is vulnerable to SQL injection!

Comment: delboy1978uk you can escape it by yourself, i gave a public idea is not a final code

Answer (score 1):

if get_price() returns a string, it should be as easy as this:

```
<p class="text-center price">From $<?= get_price($user_id , $product_id); ?></p>
```

If it's an array or something else being returned, get the result, and var dump it to see which part of the returned data is your price:

```
<?php 
$price = get_price($user_id, $product_id);
?>
<p class="text-center price">From $<?= price; ?></p>
```

If you get a message like the function doesn't exist, you need to require_once the file with the function.

Comment: Ah great! Glad I could help! Can you mark this the correct answer?